# Nuxt nuxtServerInit now being called

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to setup the store/index.js in Nuxt and don't understand why nuxtServerInit is not being called. I have added the console.log to test it out, but it doesn't seem to work or output the log.

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            loadedPosts: []
        },
        mutations: {
            setPosts(state, posts) {
                state.loadedPosts = posts;
            }
        },
        actions: {
            nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
                console.log('Init works!');

                return axios.get("<firebase.link>")
                    .then(res => {
                        const postsArray = []
                        for (const key in res.data) {
                            postsArray.push({...res.data[key], id: key})
                        }
                        vuexContext.commit('setPosts', postsArray)
                    })
                    .catch(e => context.error(e))
            },
            setPosts(vuexContext, posts) {
                vuexContext.commit('setPosts', posts)
            }
        },
        getters: {
            loadedPosts(state) {
                console.log("Here we go",state.loadedPosts);

                return state.loadedPosts
            }
        }
    })
}

export default createStore
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

The app was in **spa** mode instead of **universal**.